# How to Fit ScrollArea into Grid in QT?

Tags: qt

How to Fit ScrollArea into Grid in QT ?

I want to apply QScrollArea to this part of the grid which contains first name, lastname...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample. The size of QScrollArea is changed inside QGridLayout.

header file

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QtGui/QWidget>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>

class Widget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    QScrollArea *sca;
    QTextEdit *txt;
    QPushButton *btn;

private slots:
    void onClicked();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

source file

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QScrollBar>

Mediator::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    sca = new QScrollArea(this);
    txt = new QTextEdit;
    txt->setFixedSize(1000,500);
    btn = new QPushButton("Button",this);
    btn->setFixedSize(75,30);

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(sca);
    layout->addWidget(btn);

    sca->setWidget(txt);

    setLayout(layout);

    connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(onClicked()));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}

void Widget::onClicked()
{
    txt->setText(txt->toPlainText() + "abcd ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

QScrollArea is an ordinary widget and its size is controlled by the layout that contains it. You can change it size by calling its [resize](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#size-prop) method.

However if you need the object contaied in QScrollArea to be resized as well than you should use [QScrollArea::widgetResizable](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) property. Take a look at [Image Viewer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/widgets-imageviewer.html) example to see how the QLabel is resized along with QScrollArea.